# INA333 strange output, it's the same w/ and w/o input

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, oscilloscope, instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential

This is the EOG (Electroencephalography circuit I'm working with)
[image]

The output is essentially noise when I hook up the electrodes to myself, hence I'm debugging each stage, hooking up to an oscilloscope. Coming to the ina333, I expect to see some noisy signal with the electrodes hooked up, what I don't understand is why the oscilloscope output looks the same with and without the electrodes attached. Electrodes are on sides of the eyes on the temple side and reference at the mastoid.

oscilloscope output:

sorry about the glare, at the top is the signal and below that is the fft, a table shows the vrms and corresponding frequencies. I don't even understand where I'm getting MHz frequencies from in the first place. That's besides the point, this is the exact same screen that I look at with and without EOG_L, EOG R and REF attached to the circuit. The reference pin is connected to the supply ground, i'm pretty sure that doesn't have any affect to this issue. But I've seen people use virtual grounds instead.

Any idea where I might be going wrong? the components are hand soldered on a perf board, it's pretty messy ngl, but I've checked all the confections numerous times.
[image]

**EDIT 1:**
Based on a comment's suggestion, I added in 0.1uF decoupling capacitor  between the positive rail input of opamps and ground. Not much change tbh.
In addition to using the oscilloscope, I used a voltmeter to just center on the voltages and observe how they are being manipulated through the stages.

I'm using the INA333 amplifier as my first gain stage that takes two inputs from horizontal EOG electrodes placed on the sides of the eye close to the temple. I take the common mode at the middle of two matched gain resistors, invert it and biased against the stable 1.65V reference to feed it into the body through the reference electrode. I expect to see an amplified output by a factor of 20. But none of that happens.

With the voltmeter the inputs were around .7-.8mv and the output was between .7-.8mV. NO Change to the outputs. While common mode was around .175 mv. I also thought the voltage at the reference would be around 1.65 as it's biased to that voltage but it's ~ .8mV just like the inputs.

**EDIT 2**:
[image]

As per suggestions, I replaced the schematics with familiar opamp symbols to make it easier and understood the change in REF pin of INA333, made a stupid mistake there not centering it to the Reference voltage 1.65V.

Things I have learnt:

- Need to add low-pass filters at the INA333 input to filter all the extrinsic high-frequency noise. I understand that the differential capacitors of the low-pass filter will also help minimize effects of the high-source impedance
- The INA333 REF will need half supply to properly amplify the signal

Things that I still don't quite understand from the comments:

- Why body should be connected to the mid point bias (1.65V) than the common mode? It's totally different to what I've read. I'd really like to understand the logic behind that.
- What are things to consider to the input to IC5..it seems that is quite important, can't quite understand.
- Does the 1.65V bias to INA333 and to other opamps have to be two different supplies?

Comment: Use "decoupling" capacitor (0.1uF -- 1uF) nearest power supply pins of each opamp ...

Comment: is that really all it might be? lemme try it out and edit my question.

Comment: @Antonio51 I edited the question with new observations, do you have any input?

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your issues, but the output voltage of the inamp will have considerable effect on the reference voltage fed to the REF driver and output stage. I suggest adding a second RC filter just for the output filter on the inamp.

Comment: How are you DC biasing the inputs of the INA333? Are you connecting your body to circuit common and using that for DC bias? The mid-point bias needs lots of additional capacitance or rethinking how you bias IC5 since you're feeding the output of the INA333 to the other filter stages through the mid-point bias wire. Your schematic would be a lot easier to read if you used a standard symbol for an opamp.

Comment: The REF pin on the INA333 should be at a mid-point voltage, not ground. Your body also needs to be connected to the mid-point bias, not common. Life is made simpler by using split power supplies.

Comment: Recommend getting things working with  a function generator before trying it withelectrodes.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany how does the output voltage of ina333 have any affect on the voltage fed to REF, also where do you suggest adding a RC?

Comment: @ScottSeidman that was what I wanted to do, sadly the function generator at my lab has only one output that works. So I can’t really simulate a differential input.

Comment: @qrk sorry about the circuit, I’ll edit it with common symbols. Yes I am connecting common to the body and using that for dc bias. I’ve always understood that as the standard way to go. I don’t quite understand “mid point bias wire” and need for extra capacitances. Can you please elucidate.

Comment: @qrk wait why should the REF pin be on mid point? Does it really matter when I’m removing the offset in the filter stages. Can you please explain connecting body to mid point than common, what’s the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @qrk you’re right about the split supply, I didn’t go that approach cuz of my arc range. ADC dictates the supply ig :/

Comment: @Roshan, just the generator output  in to one side, and divide it down a hair for the other input.

Comment: Half of the voltage change at the output of the inamp, at relatively high frequencies, will show up as change in the filtered 1.65V because you effectively have two a 100k+100k voltage divider and the one to ground is only bypassed by 100nF. I suggest the inamp output RC have its own RC from the output of the regulator, maybe 10k and 100uF electrolytic.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ahh, I didn't quite notice that I had formed a 100k+100k voltage divider. In the circuit, I have an RC at the 1.65V and an RC at the inamp output. Are you saying that I should add another RC after the 100k, 0.1uF RC on the regulator?

Comment: Can you please expand on how things change at high frequencies?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @qrk ...

V+ (inputs of OP335 IC1-IC4-IC5) should be 1.65 V (?).

Note that ic6 is not "well" wired (not feedback ?)

Here is what should be done (1.65 V for Ref Input).

[image]

Comment: V+ is the supply, In+ are the inputs which are biased to 1.65. As you can see both the band pass and amplifier stage do that. IC6 is just a follower, how do you suggest it be wired?

Comment: As this one (with dual supplies) https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hyem-Saadi/publication/252020464/figure/fig1/AS:393137156575240@1470742610578/Schematic-of-the-designed-EEG-amplifier.png